# Choose a varistor for a broken PC PSU

Tags: power-supply, component-selection, varistor

My computer's PSU (Corsair RM 650X) has blown.
I've searched a bit online and I have found that this is a common defect due to a low quality varistor put in those kind of PSUs before 2018.

I know this is delicate stuff to handle so after a few months (I am using in the PC another PSU I had around) I opened it up and I confirmed that the varistor is blown.

I see that some people are replacing it with SCK035, others are choosing NTC 3D-11.

I would like to choose the component with higher quality / durability but I don't know how to read the specs sheet.

Can you help me in doing the right choice?

Comment: You need to ask a specific answerable question. You also need to edit your question with hyperlinks to the original device data sheet and the newer device data sheet and, quite possibly, state what country you are in.

Comment: SCK035 is invalid shud have 8 to 16 digits in part number https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/675066/Voltts/SCK-035/1

Comment: The power supply has 10 years warranty. Why try to fix when you can get a replacement?

Comment: I just read about the 10 years from you and... I already opened it :( I thought it had 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Quality" can mean the stress margin of the part or the design for reliability.

Here you have presented an NTC thermistor designed to reduce the massive >10x inrush surge to charging the bulk capacitors with high voltage by using a thermistor whose room temperature resistance is about 10x higher than the functional operating temperature with a load.

Factors that weigh into this design are;

- the time it takes for power to reach full voltage before power is good, and a load is applied.
- the time constant of the thermistor to reach low resistance
- the surge current ratio with rated steady current with NTC selected

  - this depends on the Q=CV storage charge in the supply to hold up the voltage for XXX watts for 1 AC cycle dropout.
- the power supplies delay constant to restart from hot,

  - often this is a couple seconds as the power declines to off before an automatic restart can begin. When hot Rt is low and a high start current will stress all the parts. (caps, diodes and NTC)
    These metal oxide parts are designed to operate at very high temperatures and even though these simple parts are reliable, Arrhenius Law states the exponential decline in reliability with rising temperature due to thermal aging.  Different component materials may operate at a lower temperature in steady state to make it more reliable and still have a 10:1 R ratio.

The problem here is the NTC has failed to protect itself.

Choosing a larger diameter part, means the thermal time constant will be longer, but it may be more robust for peak currents when the power restart dwell time is too short to cool down.

It is difficult to reason why without guessing on the system design how the part was qualified, and I have no precise datasheet for the original as the part number appears incomplete. I also do not know the replacement brand, but the datasheet looks impressive.

**Conclusion**: Technically, it's still a crap shoot without a full reliability analysis, so follow the "herd's advice" online or consider alternatives.

**Personal experience**

I do know TDK is a leader in this industry, and perhaps their part is better.  At least, the datasheet is more comprehensive, and they do not boast "Bigmaterialconstant(Bvalue),Smallremainresistance.·Highreliability." rather just "Highly stable electrical characteristic"  But that may be just a cultural difference between JP and CN.

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/epcos-tdk-electronics/B57236S0309M051/3913362